# Print 2D list in console in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, multidimensional-array, foreach, console-application

I have following code.

```cs
class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var matrix = new List<List<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        {
            string[] elements = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            matrix.Add(new List<int>());
            foreach (var item in elements)
            {
                matrix[i].Add(int.Parse(item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know to print out the array which we read from console, convert it to int from string, we will have to use foreach loop. But here to print out the list in the console how can we write the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the values line by line:

```
foreach (var line in matrix)
{
  foreach (var item in line)
  {
    Console.Write(item+"\t");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @draz exactly the type of answer I was looking for.

Comment: great! please mark the answer accordingly.

Comment: yes i can do it after 6 mins its not allowing me to do now.

Comment: ah, ok! I didn't know there is a time limit!

Comment: yh i was trying to mark it as soon as i checked its correct but couldnt. Thanks once again!

Comment: starnge, maybe it's gona work later. otherwise, never mind.

Comment: ah, here we go! :-)